# Detect the maximum amplitude of sound in an audio files like (.mp3,.WAV)

Tags: android

I want to calculate the maximum value of amplitude in an audio file. The audio file is generated after completion of the conversion of speech to text using Android speech to text converter.

Comment: you can get amplitude on recording time MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I want to do is I already have sound file and I want to calculate the maximum amplitude of sound in that file. I think  MediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude() only works when we record audio from mic of the device.

Comment: What about Visualizer.getMeasurementPeakRms() as an approximation.

Comment: Could you please provide me example code related to this method.

Comment: I don't have any sorry, I found that method while reading through the documentation.

Comment: may be you can by processing complete file start to end .